# Вложенный список

Tags: android

Можно ли сделать вложенный список? Например идет список Музыка, ТВ и т.д. Нажимаешь на Музыка и раскрывается подсписок ?

Comment: Можно. Это называется ExpandableListView. Вот, например [http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/86-urok-45-spisok-derevo-expandablelistview.html](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/86-urok-45-spisok-derevo-expandablelistview.html)

Comment: Спасибо, посмотрю сейчас.

Comment: Посмотрел я этот компонент, все вывел, но почему-то не получается реализовать событие выбора пункта. Так пишу не работает

expandableListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
CharSequence strCharSequence = ((TextView) view).getText();
String str = strCharSequence.toString().trim();
System.out.println("str = " + str);
}
}

Answer (score 1):

Как вам коллега написал, в андроиде есть стандартный компонент, но он работает на основе `ListView`. Я Вам советую посмотреть сюда [Expandable RecyclerView](http://bignerdranch.github.io/expandable-recycler-view/). Как видно из названия, это реализация на основе `RecyclerView`